# preserving whitespace when masking a String

Tags: java, string, arraylist, masking

I want to preserve the white space in the String while it is being masked. Below is the code I wrote for masking the string but it doesn't take into account that my some of my strings in my Arraylist have white space.

```
for (int i=0;i<secretWord.length();i++){
    System.out.print("*");
}
```

Comment: You can use `charAt()` and check if the current character is a whitespace or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.print(secretWord.replaceAll("\\S","*"));
```

(In a regular expression, `\S` means a single character that is not a whitespace character.)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check whether a character is space or not!

```
for (int i=0;i<secretWord.length();i++){
    if(secretWord.charAt(i)!=' ')
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
     }
}
```

Comment: I tend to use every opportunity to promote `{}` on single line `if` blocks. That way is easier to read and error-prone.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a * for a character and space for a space to mask the string.
 Do it like this:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<secretWord.length() ; i++){
        if(Character.isWhitespace(charAt(i))){
             System.out.print(charAt(i));
         }else{
             System.out.print("*");
          }
    }
```

Comment: `secretWord.charAt(i) == " "` should be `secretWord.charAt(i) == ' '`

Comment: @MikeB Thanks Mike. I forgot this is a character. :)

Comment: What about tab and other whitespace characters? See @ajb solution - it is more complex.

Comment: @VasilLukach You are right. But OP just need to retain spaces that's why.

Comment: How do you know? In question is whitespace (not space).